# ZXing.Net.Mobile on Android - Resource NotFoundException

Tags: android, xamarin, zxing

I am trying to implement ZXing.Net.Mobile on for Android and having a runtime error.

```
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(_activity);
        ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan(); // crashes here
        HandleZXingResult(result);
```

I use Xamarin for Visual Studio.

The issue seems to be about missing Resources and when it tries to `SetContentView(layout)`. I am just using the ZXing Dlls. Not sure where to include the resources.

Stack Trace:

```
06-16 01:03:44.353 I/MonoDroid( 7783): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-16 01:03:44.413 I/MonoDroid( 7783): Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Exception of type 'Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException' was thrown.
06-16 01:03:44.413 I/MonoDroid( 7783): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () 
06-16 01:03:44.413 I/MonoDroid( 7783): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896
06-16 01:03:44.413 I/MonoDroid( 7783): at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:3244
```

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon.png from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f020000
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3733)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3680)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2166)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
    at zxing.mobile.ZxingActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at zxing.mobile.ZxingActivity.onCreate(ZxingActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
    at android.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use nuget for android, Try to install components from Xamarin Component Store. It worked for me.

Comment: My issue was different. It was because of the way my projects were setup. It's all good now. Thanks again.

Comment: I also have this error - could you be more clear ito what was wrong with the project setup?

Comment: Hope you are using nuget for that by right clicking the project and selecting manage nuget option. Instead of that add component in your project.
Refer below link to add component in visual studio :
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/components_walkthrough/#Using_the_Component_Store_from_Visual_Studio

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because the zxing nuget package was referenced in a dependency assembly (our own barcode plugin assembly abstraction), but not in the parent app assembly.
Referenced the package in both projects, and then it ran fine.